# スマートコントラクト でethereum自体を取得したい

Tags: ethereum, solidity

プライベートネット上で開発しています
独自トークンではなく、ethereumの残高を取得したいのですが、以下のコードでは残高が0となってしまいます
gethで`eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])`を実行すると取得出来ることは確認出来ています

どう修正するべきでしょうか

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Balance {
    function balanceOf() public returns(uint256) {
        address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thisはコントラクト自体を指します。

なので、以下のように意味合いが変わってきます。
・address(this).balanceはコントラクトの残高を参照する
・eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])はデフォルトアカウントの残高を参照する

ユーザーのアカウントの残高を参照したい場合は、引数に参照したいアカウントのアドレスを指定してそのアドレスから参照するか、
msg.senderからトランザクション送信者のアドレスを参照するかを行えば良いと思います。

Comment: 以下のようにしてみましたが、未だ0となってしまいます  
remix で ownerをcallするとアドレスは取れます  
balanceOfは0となります  
  
    pragma solidity ^0.4.23;  
    contract Balance {  
        address public ow;  
        mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;  

        function Balance() {  
            ow = msg.sender;  
        }  
    }  
  
どうしたら良いのかわからなく

Comment: すいません、それはソース全文ですか？みたところ、balanceOf変数に代入しているところが無いように思えます

Comment: あなたのコードに　balanceOf[ ow ] = ow.balance;  を追加したら、balanceOfに残高が格納されたのをremixiで確認しました

Comment: 取得出来ました。色々と勘違いしている箇所がありました。他のアカウント指定しても取れるようになりました。